# PythonとHerokuを用いて対話型のLINEBOTの作成で困っています

Tags: python, heroku, line, デプロイ

PythonとHerokuを用いて対話型のLINEBOTを作っているのですが、いくらデプロイしても返答がうまく返信されません。
また、herokuのログを確認しても以下のようなエラーが表示されます。どうすれば改善できますか？よろしくお願いします。

補足
Windowsで作業を行っています。
また、 https://junpage.com/line-bot-development/ のサイトの作り方をもとに作業を行っております。
また、デプロイ方法ですが、このサイトの示してある通りにデプロイを行いました。

コードは以下になります。

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import requests, os
from linebot import LineBotApi, WebhookHandler
from linebot.exceptions import InvalidSignatureError
from linebot.models import MessageEvent, TextMessage, TextSendMessage, ImageMessage, ImageSendMessage, FollowEvent, UnfollowEvent
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import psycopg2


LINE_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN = "~~~~~あなたのチャネルアクセストークン~~~~~"
LINE_CHANNEL_SECRET = "~~~~~あなたのチャネルシークレット~~~~~"
DATABASE_URL = "~~~~~あなたのデータベースURL~~~~~" # 後ほどHerokuでPostgreSQLデータベースURLを取得
HEROKU_APP_NAME = "~~~~~あなたのHerokuアプリ名~~~~~" # 後ほど作成するHerokuアプリ名

app = Flask(__name__)
Heroku = "https://{}.herokuapp.com/".format(HEROKU_APP_NAME)

line_bot_api = LineBotApi(LINE_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN)
handler = WebhookHandler(LINE_CHANNEL_SECRET)

header = {
    "Content_Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + LINE_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN
}

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "hello world!"


# アプリにPOSTがあったときの処理
@app.route("/callback", methods=["POST"])
def callback():
    # get X-Line-Signature header value
    signature = request.headers["X-Line-Signature"]
    # get request body as text
    body = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    app.logger.info("Request body: " + body)
    # handle webhook body
    try:
        handler.handle(body, signature)
    except InvalidSignatureError:
        abort(400)
    return "OK"


# botにメッセージを送ったときの処理
@handler.add(MessageEvent, message=TextMessage)
def handle_message(event):
    line_bot_api.reply_message(
        event.reply_token,
        TextSendMessage(text=event.message.text))
    print("返信完了!!\ntext:", event.message.text)


# botに画像を送ったときの処理
@handler.add(MessageEvent, message=ImageMessage)
def handle_image(event):
    print("画像を受信")
    message_id = event.message.id
    image_path = getImageLine(message_id)
    line_bot_api.reply_message(
        event.reply_token,
        ImageSendMessage(
            original_content_url = Heroku + image_path["main"],
            preview_image_url = Heroku + image_path["preview"]
        )
    )
    print("画像の送信完了!!")


# 受信メッセージに添付された画像ファイルを取得
def getImageLine(id):
    line_url = f"https://api-data.line.me/v2/bot/message/{id}/content"
    result = requests.get(line_url, headers=header)
    print(result)

    img = Image.open(BytesIO(result.content))
    w, h = img.size
    if w >= h:
        ratio_main, ratio_preview = w / 1024, w / 240
    else:
        ratio_main, ratio_preview = h / 1024, h / 240

    width_main, width_preview = int(w // ratio_main), int(w // ratio_preview)
    height_main, height_preview = int(h // ratio_main), int(h // ratio_preview)

    img_main = img.resize((width_main, height_main))
    img_preview = img.resize((width_preview, height_preview))
    image_path = {
        "main": f"static/images/image_{id}_main.jpg",
        "preview": f"static/images/image_{id}_preview.jpg"
    }
    img_main.save(image_path["main"])
    img_preview.save(image_path["preview"])
    return image_path


# データベース接続
def get_connection():
    return psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode="require")


# botがフォローされたときの処理
@handler.add(FollowEvent)
def handle_follow(event):
    profile = line_bot_api.get_profile(event.source.user_id)
    with get_connection() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            conn.autocommit = True
            cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(user_id TEXT)')
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO users (user_id) VALUES (%s)', [profile.user_id])
            print('userIdの挿入OK!!')
            cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
            db = cur.fetchall()
    print("< データベース一覧 >")
    for db_check in db:
        print(db_check)


# botがアンフォロー(ブロック)されたときの処理
@handler.add(UnfollowEvent)
def handle_unfollow(event):
    with get_connection() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            conn.autocommit = True
            cur.execute('DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = %s', [event.source.user_id])
    print("userIdの削除OK!!")


# データベースに登録されたLINEアカウントからランダムでひとりにプッシュ通知
def push():
    with get_connection() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1')
            (to_user,) = cur.fetchone()
    line_bot_api.multicast([to_user], TextSendMessage(text="今日もお疲れさん!!"))


# アプリの起動
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # 初回のみデータベースのテーブル作成
    with get_connection() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            conn.autocommit = True
            cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(user_id TEXT)')
    
    # LINE botをフォローしているアカウントのうちランダムで一人にプッシュ通知
    push()
    port = int(os.getenv("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)
### End
```

プロックファイルの中身は以下のようにしてあります。

```
web: python main.py
```

また、`heroku logs` でログを確認するとこのようにエラーが表示されます。

```
Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 8.5.0.
2023-11-13T19:38:41.227541+00:00 app[web.1]: handler = WebhookHandler(LINE_CHANNEL_SECRET)
2023-11-13T19:38:41.260711+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-11-13T19:38:41.260713+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 150, in <module>
2023-11-13T19:38:41.260845+00:00 app[web.1]: push()
2023-11-13T19:38:41.260877+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 137, in push
2023-11-13T19:38:41.260925+00:00 app[web.1]: (to_user,) = cur.fetchone()
2023-11-13T19:38:41.260956+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-13T19:38:41.260964+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
2023-11-13T19:38:41.385596+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-11-13T19:38:41.413061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-11-14T01:06:58.771692+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-11-14T01:07:02.498837+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python main.py`
2023-11-14T01:07:03.554890+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/main.py:19: LineBotSdkDeprecatedIn30: Call to deprecated class LineBotApi. (Use v3 class; linebot.v3.<feature>. See https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-python/blob/master/README.rst for more details.) -- Deprecated since version 3.0.0.
2023-11-14T01:07:03.554914+00:00 app[web.1]: line_bot_api = LineBotApi(LINE_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN)
2023-11-14T01:07:03.554931+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/main.py:20: LineBotSdkDeprecatedIn30: Call to deprecated class WebhookHandler. (Use 'from linebot.v3.webhook import WebhookHandler' instead. See https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-python/blob/master/README.rst for more details.) -- Deprecated since version 3.0.0.
2023-11-14T01:07:03.554932+00:00 app[web.1]: handler = WebhookHandler(LINE_CHANNEL_SECRET)
2023-11-14T01:07:03.579665+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-11-14T01:07:03.579671+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 150, in <module>
2023-11-14T01:07:03.579802+00:00 app[web.1]: push()
2023-11-14T01:07:03.579846+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 137, in push
2023-11-14T01:07:03.579919+00:00 app[web.1]: (to_user,) = cur.fetchone()
2023-11-14T01:07:03.579958+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-14T01:07:03.579968+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
2023-11-14T01:07:03.706332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-11-14T01:07:03.731035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-11-14T06:51:21.555943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-11-14T06:51:24.991038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python main.py`
2023-11-14T06:51:26.025249+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/main.py:19: LineBotSdkDeprecatedIn30: Call to deprecated class LineBotApi. (Use v3 class; linebot.v3.<feature>. See https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-python/blob/master/README.rst for more details.) -- Deprecated since version 3.0.0.
2023-11-14T06:51:26.025266+00:00 app[web.1]: line_bot_api = LineBotApi(LINE_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN)
2023-11-14T06:51:26.025293+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/main.py:20: LineBotSdkDeprecatedIn30: Call to deprecated class WebhookHandler. (Use 'from linebot.v3.webhook import WebhookHandler' instead. See https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-python/blob/master/README.rst for more details.) -- Deprecated since version 3.0.0.
2023-11-14T06:51:26.025293+00:00 app[web.1]: handler = WebhookHandler(LINE_CHANNEL_SECRET)
2023-11-14T06:51:26.050262+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-11-14T06:51:26.050263+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 150, in <module>
2023-11-14T06:51:26.050342+00:00 app[web.1]: push()
2023-11-14T06:51:26.050368+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 137, in push
2023-11-14T06:51:26.050416+00:00 app[web.1]: (to_user,) = cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: この質問文ですと、読んだ側からすると「HTTPステータスが503=何かしらの理由でサーバーがレスポンスを返せない」以上の情報が存在しない状態です。そのため原因の判定もほぼ不可能なので回答がつくことが非常に難しくなっています。
まずは、質問文を編集して「Pythonのコード（どのようなアプリケーションコードを実装したのか）」「Procfile等（どのような形式でデプロイしたのか）」を提示することころから実施してみてください。
（トークンなどの秘匿すべき情報を掲載しないように注意してください）

Comment: ログに `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object` と表示されています。つまり、`cur.fetchone()` が `None` を返しているということなので、query の結果が 0 件ということなのでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。具体的にはどこを修正すればよろしいでしょうか

Comment: エラーの発生箇所はログに表示されています。(`push()` 関数内の `(to_user,) = cur.fetchone()` です)

Comment: main.pyの137行目の(to_user,) = cur.fetchone()の場所でよろしいでしょうか？また、どのように直せばいいですか？よろしくお願いします。